# Allow textbox to use just alphabetic characters

Tags: textbox, integer

Well i m working on my project that is a car parts program in visual basic,i want to protect my textbox in the clients when the user insert a client i dont want the name allow numbers just strings how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this
you can check the text ie `TextBox2.Text`  to make sure it has nothing besides alphabet characters in the content using regular expression

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Leave
  If Not Regex.Match(TextBox2.Text, "^[a-z]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success Then
    MsgBox("Please enter alphabetic text only.")
    TextBox2.Focus()
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply

Comment: I m having a problem 

Regex.Match(TextBox2.Text, "^[a-z]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

The regex in underlined and says it cant be acessed, by the way i m using mysql is there any problem for that?

Comment: @user2423011 are you using visual basic or any other language can you show your code here...

Comment: Private Sub TextBox2_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Leave
        If Not Regex.Match(TextBox2.Text, "^[a-z]*$", RptionegexOs.IgnoreCase).Success Then
            MsgBox("Please enter alphabetic text only.")
            TextBox2.Focus()
        End If

    End Sub

Comment: it says it can be acessed can you give me some help please?

Comment: what is your text field name..is it TextBox2

Comment: yes i m using a variable called name to acess the content of the textbox

Comment: conexao.Open()

            Dim nome As String
      
            nome = TextBox2.Text

Comment: did you imported the reg class `import System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Comment: yes now yes the error helped me but now how i call the function with the parameters?

Comment: you are saying about the function for textbox2 .

Comment: This will automatically catch an error when the user tabs to the next control.did you checked this ?

Comment: no its not that i dont know how to use the function how i call it? i just write in the code textbox2_leave?

Comment: the `Leave` is the event when you leave from the current field to another it will execute If you want to stop the user as soon as a non-alpha key is pressed, you can use the `TextChanged` event instead of the `Leave` event

Comment: ohh i can see it let me try it

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Button1.Text = "Inserir" Then
            Button1.Text = "Guardar"
            ProtecaoTextBox(TabPage1, True)
            Protecaolabelgroup(TabPage1, True)
            TextBox1.Visible = False
            TextBox2_Leave()
            'Bloquear os botoes alterar/editar e inserir'
            Button2.Enabled = False
            Button3.Enabled = False

Comment: but i dont understand how i can call it the procedure

Comment: can you tell me which project you doing is it a web based project or window based project ....

Comment: @user2423011 i am not sure what is the issue you experiencing as the code i have added should work .You should check it by event wise where it is falling using step by step debugging.i can add 2-3 more validations but i am not sure how you using it..

Comment: well if you want to post them tomorrow i will try again thanks for the help